# How do I hide an specific division when someone clicks an button with HTML, JS or Ajax?

Tags: javascript, html

So i want to hide (better to say toggle) some division when someone clicks an button. I have more than 20 division and 20 button, each button should close the specified division. For easier understanding lets do it just with one division and one button.

so i have 2 parts, here is what i tried:
html part which I have

```
<div class="sssadsa" id="buttonsdiv">
  <button id="thebutton" type="button" onclick="toggleDiv(divtohide0);">
    <h3>Scene 1</h3>
  </button>
</div>

<div id="divtohide0">
 some content
</div>
```

and this is my WHOLe javascript which  I have 
but somehow I cannot manage it to get working, the js doesn't do anything when clicking the button. not even the alert("hello world");

```
function toggleDiv(id){

  alert("hello world -back to the roots" );

  event.preventDefault();
  $('#' + id).toggle(); // Toggle div visibility
}
```

Comment: It might sound banal, but have you attached the function to a click event? I mean: `$(`my-division-list button`).click(function(event) { toggleDiv(event.target.id) })`

Comment: noop, that is my whole javascript code

Comment: I tought the parameter " onclick="toggleDiv(divtohide0);" " from the html is calling the function allready -Am i thinking here wrong? Coming kind of from Java developoment. How should i do this than? I need each button to call with its specified ID (in this example "divtohide0" ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be several things that might occur.

1. Your javascript isn't loaded (try running a `console.log` outside the function and check if you see anything. If you don't check the way you are loading the script)
2. `toggleDiv` isn't available globally (try adding `window.toggleDiv = toggleDiv` after you declared the function)

If any of the above doesn't work, leave a comment.

Also note the following errors in your code:

1. You cannot call the `event` if you pass another parameter (eg: `divtohide0`).
2. You need to use a string to pass the id, otherwise javascript will expect a variable. (eg: `toggleDiv('divtohide0');`)
3. I suggest you to avoid adding a `h3` tag inside a `button`. If you need to style the content do it with a class.

In the snipper there is another function where the event works which require a data argument on the `button`. But there are several ways to achieve the same result.

```js
function toggleDiv(id){

  alert("hello world -back to the roots" );

  // event.preventDefault(); this won't work
  $('#' + id).toggle(); // Toggle div visibility
}

function toggleDivWithEvent(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var id = $(event.target).data('target-id');
  $('#' + id).toggle(); // Toggle div visibility
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="sssadsa" id="buttonsdiv">
  <button id="thebutton" type="button" onclick="toggleDiv('divtohide0');">
    <h3>Scene 1</h3>
  </button>
</div>

<div id="divtohide0">
 some content
</div>


<div class="sssadsa" id="buttonsdiv">
  <button id="thebutton" type="button" data-target-id="divtohide1" onclick="toggleDivWithEvent(event)">
    <h3>Scene 1</h3>
  </button>
</div>

<div id="divtohide1">
 some content
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you it seems i had an very stup*d logical problem. This solved my problem perfectly :)